# Can't connect to Redis by My IP address

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I have Redis as a server and also a client which read and write the server. 
When I run the command `redis-cli ping` I see the `PONG` response, and also my application works fine.

After that, I comment `bind` config in **redis.conf** for everyone can see the Redis port(6379), but when I execute the command `redis-cli -h <my-ip> ping` I see the following result:

**Error: The disk is in use or locked by another process.**

Actually, I want to run a Redis instance on my windows 7 and everyone and I can connect to that as clients. I know that I can connect with localhost but I don't know why I can't connect by my IP? What is the problem?

(The Redi version is: 3.2.100 )

Comment: did you kill the previous redis process? it looks the redis db is left as locked

Comment: yes, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Please look for `protected-mode` setting in your config file and set it to `no` after reading the description of that option. Excerpt from default config file:

> Protected mode is a layer of security protection, in order to avoid that
>   Redis instances left open on the internet are accessed and exploited.
>
> When protected mode is on and if:
>
> 1) The server is not binding explicitly to a set of addresses using the
>      "bind" directive.
>
> 2) No password is configured.
>
> **The server only accepts connections from clients connecting from the
>   IPv4 and IPv6 loopback addresses 127.0.0.1 and ::1, and from Unix domain
>   sockets**.
>
> **By default protected mode is enabled**. You should disable it only if
>   you are sure you want clients from other hosts to connect to Redis
>   even if no authentication is configured, nor a specific set of interfaces
>   are explicitly listed using the "bind" directive.
>
> protected-mode yes

Comment: This is wrong. It will work with protected mode yes itself

Comment: It is not wrong, but just the simplest solution to OP's problem. By reading the above excerpt one can clearly see that `protected-mode yes` will still work, but at least one other condition must be fulfilled (either explicit bind to an IP address or password).